Spotify API always returns 429 on certain endpoints
Certain endpoints on Spotify audiobooks API always return a 429, regardless of how many calls I've made. E.g. https://api.spotify.com/v1/audiobooks?ids=16rRc378Jq4lwl5t64CdA3&access_token=mytokenhere always returns a 429, as does https://api.spotify.com/v1/audiobooks/16rRc378Jq4lwl5t64CdA3/chapters?access_token=urtoken. (For the avoidance of doubt, I am including the actual token not these holder tokens). What's up with that?

Do you receive any useful headers in payload in response from the API, like when to retry? According to https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/concepts/rate-limits , rate limits apply based on 30 second window, do you make calls frequently? Is your app in development mode?
